# Axios instance promise.all error handling

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, rxjs, axios

I have the following code in my own `async` function that uses another imported function from module which is a custom wrap of **[axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)** inside `try/catch` block:

```
async function getCharacter (realmSlug, characterName) {
    try {
        const [{id, name, gender, faction, race, character_class, active_spec, realm, guild, level, last_login_timestamp, average_item_level, equipped_item_level}, {pets, unlocked_battle_pet_slots},{mounts}] = await Promise.all([
            getCharacterSummary(realmSlug, characterName), -- custom axios instance
            getCharacterPetsCollection(realmSlug, characterName),
            getCharacterMountsCollection(realmSlug, characterName)
        ])
        ....
        return result;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.code);
        if (error.response.status === 404 || error.response.status === 403) {
            console.error(`${getCharacter.name},${characterName}@${realmSlug}`);
        }
        return { name: characterName, realm: realmSlug }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I use `promise.all` according to Stackoverflow [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072844/error-handling-with-promise-all),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30362733/handling-errors-in-promise-all) I can not handle errors. So the problem is when I call function to execute, my errors doesn't handle in `(catch)` block. At all. Even if I don't need print them, anyway I receive messages in console about `404 errors`, but `console.log(error.code)` still gives me nothing. For example:

[image]

So is there any way to handle this annoying error messages in console somehow? 
For example using `.catch` somewhere? Or using `for await ... of` or [rxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) instead if it's possible?

> Exporting function and using .catch

Even if I export this function `getCharacter` in another `.js` file and use the following code:

```
const getCharacter = require('./getCharacter');

               let bulkCharacters = [{realmSlug, characterName},{realmSlug, characterName},... ,n] //array of characters for getCharacter request
               const promises = bulkCharacters.map(async ({realmSlug, characterName}) => {
                    try {
                        return await getCharacter(realmSlug, characterName);
                    } catch (e) {
                        console.log(e)
                    }
                });
                let test = await Promise.all(promises)
                    .catch(function(arrayOfPromises, err) {
                        // log that I have an error, return the entire array;
                        console.log('A promise failed to resolve', err);
                        return arrayOfPromises;
                    })
                    .then(function(arrayOfPromises) {
                        console.log(arrayOfPromises)
                    })
                ;
                console.log('stop')
```

I still receive errors in console, without triggering `catch` block inside `getCharacter` function or this file in which this function was imported and `catch` block is outside the function.

Comment: You can use `.catch()` directly on `Promise.all()` and return whatever you want. You can then throw an error after the `await Promise.all()` finishes

Comment: @mhodges Thank you for mentioning it, but I guess, I already found the problem in imported module function that was wrapped in axios. That's why `catch` block never triggers.